# PHP Post request returns 'Error'.why?

Tags: php, post

my php POST request script always returns error,and i have no idea why.
i tried different approaches and still no luck.
when i try this, it returns 
'Not Found
Sorry, we could not find a page at that URL.'

why?there is a page at that URL 100%

here is the code

```
$params = array(
    'apiKey' =>'*********',
    'titleID' => $title,
    'forename' => $yname,
    'surname' => $surname,
    'dayPhone' => $phone,
    'eveningPhone' => $phone_evening,
    'mobilePhone' => $phone_mobile,
     'email' => $email,
     'buyingBedrooms' => $bedroom_num,
     'buyingMinPrice' => $min_budget,
     'buyingMaxPrice' => $max_budget,
     'buyingNotes' => $message,
     'buyingActive' => true
    );

function httpPost($url,$params)
{
$postData = '';
 foreach($params as $k => $v) 
 { 
  $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
 }
 $postData = rtrim($postData, '&');

 $ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);    

$output=curl_exec($ch);

if($output === false)
{
    echo "Error Number:".curl_errno($ch)."<br>";
    echo "Error String:".curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
return $output;

}
echo httpPost("http://daisylets.domus.net/site/go/api/saveRegistration",$params);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You shoudl contact the owner of the api and ask what the problem is. We can't help you without knowing what the api is and what it does.

Comment: basically it just saves the applicat registration in the database.in the documentation there is only url 'http://daisylets.domus.net/site/go/api/saveRegistration', and different parameters overview.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the data, it is impossible to tell, but a potential problem is that you could be breaking your own query string:

```
$postData = '';
foreach($params as $k => $v) 
{ 
  $postData .= $k . '='.$v.'&'; 
}
$postData = rtrim($postData, '&');
```

You are not encoding your values so any character that has a special meaning in a url / has to be encoded in a url, will break your cURL request.

You should replace that whole section with just:

```
$postData = http_build_query($params);
```

Comment: i removed that block and replaced it with pre-build data.$params = array( 'apiKey' =>'***', 'titleID' => 'mr', 'forename' => 'test', 'surname' => 'test', 'dayPhone' => '07729720310', 'eveningPhone' => '07729720310', 'mobilePhone' => '07729720310', 'email' => 'test@hot.ee', 'buyingBedrooms' => '4', 'buyingMinPrice' => '100000', 'buyingMaxPrice' => '666666', 'buyingNotes' => 'hello', 'buyingActive' => true ); Now it Gives me next error .Expectation Failed Expect: 100-continue Only the 100-continue expectation is supported. –

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding the URL

```
$postUrl = urlencode("http://daisylets.domus.net/site/go/api/saveRegistration");
echo httpPost($postUrl,$params);
```

Comment: just tried,gives this error now Error Number:6
Error String:Could not resolve host: http%3A%2F%2Fdaisylets.domus.net%2Fsite%2Fgo%2Fapi%2FsaveRegistration; Name or service not known // - See more at: http://daisylets.uk/wptest/reg-form.php#sthash.BYzrI3pP.dpuf